# how to check the backend server health with https haproxy

Tags: ssl, backend, haproxy, health-check

I'm using yum to install haproxy 1.5.18 .
THere are two types of backend server, one type is https backend servers, one type is http backend servers. any type has two servers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewRy8.jpg)

in the previous configuration for http visit( both haproxy and was ), i can use

```
option httpchk HEAD /sabrix/scripts/menu-common.js
```

to detect whether the web service (http://aaa1.lenovo.com:9080/sabrix ) was working properly and it works fine. but when i want to use to detect https backend server , i found it failed.

mode http

```
balance roundrobin
option redispatch
option httpchk HEAD /sabrix/scripts/menu-common.js
server sabrix1 10.99.202.100:443 ssl check-ssl verify none
server sabrix2 10.99.202.218:443 ssl check-ssl verify none
```

i also tried with

```
   option httpchk GET /check
```

but both are failed.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/924477/haproxy-health-check-for-https-backend

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both the `check` argument (to enable any checks on the server) as well as the `check-ssl` argument (to run checks over SSL). Your backend might thus look like this:

```
balance roundrobin
option redispatch
option httpchk HEAD /sabrix/scripts/menu-common.js
server sabrix1 10.99.202.100:443 ssl verify none check check-ssl
server sabrix2 10.99.202.218:443 ssl verify none check check-ssl
```

Comment: your comments are pretty helpful  for most of my environments, but in few condiftion, i also need to apply my domain root.ca to os level.  Overall, i need show my great thanks to you, thank you so much .